# gcloud auth throws PyOpenSSL is not available

Tags: google-compute-engine, travis-ci, gcloud

I've been trying to get gcloud to a usable state on Travis and I just can't seem to get passed the `gcloud auth activate-service-account` point.

When ever it runs I just get the following error:

```
ERROR: (gcloud.auth.activate-service-account) PyOpenSSL is not available. 
See https://developers.google.com/cloud/sdk/crypto for details.
```

I've tried apt-get and pip installs both with the `export CLOUDSDK_PYTHON_SITEPACKAGES=1` set and nothing seems to work.

Does anyone have any ideas or alternatives?

This is Travis version Ubuntu 14.04.

### Update

If I run the command from the docs on travis I get the following error:

```
usage: gcloud auth activate-service-account  ACCOUNT --key-file KEY_FILE [optional flags]
ERROR: (gcloud.auth.activate-service-account) too few arguments
```

This made me think I had to have an `ACCOUNT` parameter, but after running the command locally with the un-encrypted service account key, I know it's not needed (unless something has changed).

The only other thing I can think of is that the file isn't be decrypted correctly or the command itself isn't happy in Travis:

```
- gcloud auth activate-service-account --key-file client-secret.json
```

### Update 2

Just dumped a load of logs to figure what is going on. (Massive shout out to @Vilas for his help)

It looks like `gcloud` is installed on the VM for node already, but it's a super old version.

```
$ which gcloud
/usr/bin/gcloud

$ gcloud --version
Google Cloud SDK 0.9.37
bq 2.0.18
bq-nix 2.0.18
compute 2014.11.25
core 2014.11.25
core-nix 2014.11.25
dns 2014.11.25
gcutil 1.16.5
gcutil-nix 1.16.5
gsutil 4.6
gsutil-nix 4.6
sql 2014.11.25
```

The next question is how can I get the path to find the right gcloud?

I've confirmed that the downloaded SDK installs to ${HOME}/google-cloud-sdk/bin by running this command.

```
$ ls -l ${HOME}/google-cloud-sdk/bin
total 24
drwxr-xr-x 2 travis travis 4096 Apr 27 21:44 bootstrapping
-rwxr-xr-x 1 travis travis 3107 Mar 28 14:53 bq
-rwxr-xr-x 1 travis travis  912 Apr 21 18:56 dev_appserver.py
-rwxr-xr-x 1 travis travis 3097 Mar 28 14:53 gcloud
-rwxr-xr-x 1 travis travis 3144 Mar 28 14:53 git-credential-gcloud.sh
-rwxr-xr-x 1 travis travis 3143 Mar 28 14:53 gsutil
```

Comment: Can you use .json keys instead? This is only required if you use the deprecated .p12 keys.

Comment: both the files I've tried have been json. Do you know what the format should be? I realised at first I was using an oauth cert from than service account cert, but still no joy after fixing it.

Comment: Can you follow the instructions here and see if that works for you: https://cloud.google.com/solutions/continuous-delivery-with-travis-ci

Comment: That's what I've been using and I'm now at a point where the only thing I can think of being the problem is that the decryption step is failing although that seems wrong given the error code of "ERROR: (gcloud.auth.activate-service-account) too few arguments" - surely "Key file not found" or "Key file not parseable" would be the kind of error message I'd get.

Comment: Which version of Cloud SDK are you using? Older versions required that your always provided an account/email-address argument as well as the key-file. Newer versions do not ask for account if you provide a valid .json key file.

Comment: @Vilas it looks like you've hit the nail on the head.

The version Travis is getting is "Google Cloud SDK 0.9.37" - Any ideas on why this might be? I'm using the same technique with "curl https://sdk.cloud.google.com | bash" as the tutorial and I've removed the caching of the directory to remove that as a possibility.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally got a solution for it. Essentially Travis has a super old version of the gcloud SDK installed that was taking presidence over the downloaded SDK.

## Steps to Help Diagnose

1. In your `.travis.yml` file add:

   ```
   env:
     global:
       # Ensure the downloaded SDK is first on the PATH
       - PATH=${HOME}/google-cloud-sdk/bin:$PATH
       # Ensure the install happens without prompts
       - CLOUDSDK_CORE_DISABLE_PROMPTS=1
   ```
2. Then in your install step add the following:

   ```
   install:
   # Make sure SDK is downloaded - cache once it's working
   # NOTE: Note sure how to update the SDK if it's cached
   - curl https://sdk.cloud.google.com | bash;
   # List the SDK contents to ensure it's downloaded
   - ls -l ${HOME}/google-cloud-sdk/bin
   # Ensure the correct gcloud is being used
   - which gcloud
   # Print the gcloud version and make sure it's something
   # Reasonably up to date compared with: 
   # https://cloud.google.com/sdk/downloads#versioned
   - gcloud --version
   ```

Comment: You may not need to do all this. If there is an old version of gcloud already installed, just run `gcloud components update --quiet`. That should update it to the latest version.

Comment: Tried that and it through an error, something along the lines of components not being disabled or not installed with the SDK